# Are chaotic function one way?

Tags: cryptography, chaos-theory

Are chaotic functions also one way functions? Can they be used in cryptography?

Comment: You can use points on a Lorenz attractor for encrypting and use the value of $p$ as key. The question is, is there a way to reverse a chaotic function without know initial conditions?

Comment: How do you define a chaotic function?

Comment: All functions where a "nearby" input does not return a "nearby" output

Comment: How do you define "nearby"? Say the input is a binary string of a specific length, do you use hamming distance? [This](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16144/are-hash-functions-chaotic) might be of interest.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you defined what you meant by one-way functions. Because one-way functions have never been proven to exist (in the theoretical sense). Proving that a one-way function exists proves that $P\neq NP$. So you must have some other definition of one-way function.

Comment: Wow you perfectly understood what I was looking for. If a function is one way (until someone prove that $P=NP$) then it can be used for hashing. A part that I don't write in this question is if can I use strange attractors to hash.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understood it at all :) I have no idea what "strange attractors" are.

Answer (score 1):

> Are chaotic functions also one way functions?

In the cryptographic sense? That really depends on the specific function. In general, I would guess that the answer is no. In the theoretic sense, no. Because if they were, we'd know that $P\neq NP$. We don't know that yet, so there obviously are no chaotic functions that are one way functions (again, in the theoretic sense).

> Can they be used in cryptography?

Depends on what you mean. In general no, though, given your fuzzy definition of a chaotic function, it seems that most cryptographic primitives (hash functions, block ciphers, etc) meet your definition.

In other words, give me a chaotic function and it may or may not be useful in cryptography. Give me a cryptographic function (hash, block cipher, etc) and it appears to be chaotic (by your definition).

Most cryptographers don't discuss this property. Instead we talk about the [avalanche effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect).

Comment: So, if I understood, all cryptographic functions are chaotic but not all chaotic functions are useful for cryptography.